# Testing a fiber coupled white light source OSL2 ( Thorlabs)

Tags: quantum-optics

I have ordered a fiber-coupled white light source OSL2 from Thorlabs company I will use it in quantum dots spectroscopy. But I don´t know how can I test it. Can you tell me please how can I do the experiment to test OSL2?

Comment: I want to test the range of wavelengths